# How do I test if all minecraft players on a server are in a radius?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This has got me. I need a command that tells me if all players on a server are in a radius of a command block. If one of them isn't in the radius, the command will be false. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use a command block with the command `/testfor @a[rm=RADIUS]`. point a comparator from the command block into another block, and on that block, place a redstone torch. This tests if anyone is outside of the radius, and inverts the signal, providing the output you want.

Comment: I don't like mixing command blocks with redstone, and neither should you.  I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: What's the problem with mixing those ?.. Command blocks without redstone wont work...

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot Blocks updates are a major source of lag when it comes to command block mechanisms; the fewer block updates the better. As of 1.9, it's quite easy to avoid all block updates. Not to mention that relying on physical logic is almost never multiplayer-friendly, though in this case multiplayer-friendliness isn't barred.

Comment: @MBraedley most large projects require more than one chained command, and since there are no turing-complete equivalent conditional operators available in command blocks, redstone is necessary for projects like this

Comment: @Inori: No, you are quite wrong on that.  If memory serves, all that's needed for Turing-completeness is `NOT` and `AND`, which is easily accomplished.

Comment: @MBraedley functional programming takes more than just binary gates. Speaking of, those are also conventionally accomplished with redstone.

Comment: @Inori I'm going to put this simply: command blocks, especially in 1.9, are Turing complete if we ignore the infinite memory requirement.  The only significant hurdle to functional programming with command blocks is nested and or multi-variable `if-then-else`, but they are still doable.

Answer (score 3):

A block-updateless method would be to use 1.9's new command blocks with the "conditional" setting, as well as using `/testforblock` to check the success of a command.

Image example:

[image: Repeating > chain > conditional chain]

1. Look for players *outside* the area. This has been reduced to 1 player, as otherwise the command is processed equal to the number of players outside the area. All we need to know is if there's at least 1.

   ```
   /testfor @a[rm=10,c=1]
   ```
2. Check the `SuccessCount` value of the Repeating command block. Replace the XYZ values with that of the Repeating command block. If the value was 0, that means no players were found.

   ```
   /testforblock X Y Z minecraft:repeating_command_block -1 {SuccessCount:0}
   ```
3. **Conditional.** Command to run based on there being no players outside the area.

   ```
   /say No players outside the area.
   ```

To further reduce server strain, you can disable output tracking on the command blocks. Do so by clicking the "O" button in the interface so that it turns into an "X":

[image: Command block interface]

Comment: This is one of the very few instances where `testfor` is the right command for the job.